# How can I make disk image without free space?

Tags: disk-usage, disk-image, free

I want to make disk image in case if something goes wrong. I found few topics and method about zeroing free space, but people also said that method is not safe for SSD. Then I found other method - [Create A Disk Image Without Enough Free Space](http://dustymabe.com/2012/11/15/create-a-disk-image-without-enough-free-space/), but it is a bit old and I don't know if it works on 14.04 with SSD.
Can I do that by following that guide? If no, please tell me some other method, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks safe enough. I have a SSD too, and I have done something similar, and it didn't wreck my disk.

Disclaimer: If this breaks your disk, please tell me, but I am just saying what I think.

Comment: Can you please post method you used and worked for you? I don't want to risk breaking SSD.

Comment: I used clonezilla with dd and a compression method similar. I can't exactly remember the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I find the page you linked to is safe. It simply uses dd to read the whole disk, and then use cp to make a copy of the disk image to handle sparse file so that the result disk image is small. So the operation is mainly just read from the disk, and so it won't hurt your SSD. I think what you read about unsafe for SSD is something around the trim operation? This is unrelated to what you are trying to do.